# Show that $S/x^kS$ is a flat $T[x]/x^k$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be an $T[[x]]$-module and $S$ is $x$-torsion free module, $S$ is $x$-adically complete, $S/xS$ is finitely generated projective.

> Then we have to show that $S/x^kS$ is a flat $T[x]/x^k$-module for each $k \geq 1$.

**My approach:**

Since $S$ is $x$-torsion free, the multiplication map (by $x$) $:S \xrightarrow{x} S$ is injective.

So for $k,l \geq 1$, we have the following short exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to S/x^k S \xrightarrow{x^l} S/x^{k+l} S \to S/x^l M \to 0. $$
Now we know the following two results,

> (i)If $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $I$ be an ideal of $A$, then the completion $A \to \hat A$ is flat with respect to $I$.
>
> (ii)  A $R$-module $M$ is flat if and only if it is a direct limit of finitely-generated free modules.

Also we have $R[x]/(x^k) \simeq R[[x]]/(x^k)$ under completion with respect to $x$-adic topology.

How can I use the above two results $(i), (ii)$ to show that $S/x^kS$ is a flat $T[x]/x^k$-module ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is not correct as stated. Let $T=\Bbb Z$ and $S=(\Bbb Z/2)[[x]]$ with the obvious $T[[x]]$ module structure. Then $S$ is $x$-torsion free, but $S/xS \cong \Bbb Z/2$ which is not a flat $\Bbb Z$-module.

Comment: @KReiser, $S$ is $x$-torsion free module, $S$ is $x$-adically complete, $S/xS$ is finitely generated projective. Do $S$ in your example satisfies all ? I think your $S$ is not complete

Comment: The $S$ in my example satisfies all those properties except for $S/xS$ projective, and each of these are fairly quick to check. The reason this was a counterexample before your edit is that you did not initially include all of these assumptions.

Comment: @KReiser, ok. So $S/xS$ should help to conclude the proof